# Send data request by php to flask API

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, api, flask

I'm trying to send data by self-made Flask  API .
this is my api code :

```
def add_message(uuid):
    content = request.json
    try:
     print(content['mytext'])
    except:print(content)
    return jsonify({"uuid":uuid})
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

if I am sending data via python everything works :

```
res = requests.get('https://**.pythonanywhere.com/123', json={"mytext":"test"})
if res.ok:
    print( res.json())
```

but if i using php :

```
$host = "https://**.pythonanywhere.com";

$url = $host.'/1237R4';

echo http($url,json_encode([
    "mytext"=>"python rules"
]),'post');
function http($url,$data=[],$method='get'){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $chOpts = [
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
        CURLOPT_HEADER=>false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT =>8,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 16,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,[
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ]
    ];
    if($method=='post'){
        $chOpts[CURLOPT_POST]=true;
        $chOpts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]=$data;
        $chOpts[CURLOPT_URL]=$url;
    }
    else{
        $url.='?'.is_array($data)?http_build_query($data):$data;
        $chOpts[CURLOPT_URL]=$url;
    }
    echo 'Request: '.$method.'['.$url.']'."\n";
    print_r($data);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $chOpts);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

i got the following error in logs :

```
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message text is empty"}']
```

How to make it working for php ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$req = $http({method: 'get',url: "https://**.pythonanywhere.com/123",params: {mytext: "test"});
```

now the `mytext` became string, you were not passing it as a string.

Comment: i edited question , i tryed string too  and  its not worked